# Increasing accuracy/computation error

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, classification

In order to increase the accuracy of my classification,I need to increase the number of training data, or no. of the classifier trees. However, whenever I do any of those options, I got an error of computation value is too large/timed out.
I even exported my inputProperties as a stacked layer to give some space for computation, but still get the error. Can anyone help with that?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/64116658f61637d18397aab03d098a37

```
// // //Generate  random pt sample
var random1 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: Rice,
  points: 16000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
});
var random2 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: Maize,
  points: 20000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
});

var random3 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: cotton,
  points: 14000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
})

var random4 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: potato,
  points: 14000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
});
var random5 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: water,
  points: 5000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
});
var random6 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: Urban,
  points: 5000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
});

var random7 = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints({
  region: Wheat,
  points: 15000,
  seed: 0,
  maxError: 0.1,
})


var referenceData = ee.Image().byte()
                  .paint(Rice, 0)
                  .paint(Maize, 1)
                  .paint(cotton,2)
                  .paint(potato,3)
                  .paint(water,4)
                  .paint(Urban,5)
                  .paint(Wheat,6)
                  .rename("class"); 

// // // // // // // Place the collections in a new collection.
//var combined = ee.FeatureCollection([random1,random2,random3,random4,random5,random6,random7]);
// Combine all of the random point feature collections into a single collection.
var flattened = ee.FeatureCollection([random1, random2, random3, random4, random5, random6, random7])
  .flatten(); //
//

// // // // // Flatten the collection to create a new collection with all the features.

//var flattened= random1.merge(random2).merge(random3).merge(random4).merge(random5).merge(random6).merge(random7);//;//.merge(random4)
// Simplify the geometries in the flattened collection.
var simplified = flattened.map(function(feature) {
  var simplifiedGeometry = feature.geometry().simplify(10000);
  return feature.setGeometry(simplifiedGeometry);
});

// // // Get the values for all pixels in each polygon in the training.
var training = stacked.addBands(referenceData).reduceRegions({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.first(),
  // Get the sample from the polygons FeatureCollection.
  collection:simplified,//flattened,
  scale: 30,
  tileScale: 16
});


// //How balanced are the training data?
// //print(training.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(), ["class"]));
 Map.addLayer(training,{},'training_sample',false);

// Filter out the null property values and try again.
var trainingNoNulls = training.filter(
  ee.Filter.notNull(stacked.bandNames().add("class"))
)
var sample=trainingNoNulls.randomColumn();
var split=0.7
var training_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random',split));
var validation_sample=sample.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random',split));
//print(training_sample,'training_sample')



var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(300)
  .train({
    features: training_sample,
    //.randomColumn().filter("random < 0.7"),
    classProperty: 'class',
    inputProperties: stacked.bandNames(),//bands//
    
  })

var classified = stacked.classify(classifier, 'Classified');

Map.addLayer(classified.randomVisualizer(),{},'classification', false);

// Get a confusion matrix representing resubstitution accuracy.
var trainAccuracy = classifier.confusionMatrix();
print('Resubstitution error matrix: ', trainAccuracy);
print('Training overall accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Training kappa accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.kappa());
//print('Training producer accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.producersAccuracy());
//print('Training Consumer accuracy: ', trainAccuracy.consumersAccuracy());


// // // // // //////////// validation sample//////

//Extract spectral data from the input image for validation points
var validation = stacked.sampleRegions({
  // Get the sample from the point FeatureCollection.
  collection: validation_sample,
  // We'll classify on 'Level_2"
properties: ['class'],
  // Set the scale to get Sentinel-2 pixels at the points.
  scale: 30,
  tileScale: 2
})

// Classify the validation data.
var validated = validation.classify(classifier);

// Get a confusion matrix representing expected accuracy.
var testAccuracy = validated.errorMatrix('class', 'classification');
print('Test overall accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());
print('Test kappa accuracy: ', testAccuracy.kappa());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some things you can do to use less memory, however, if your covariates don't actually contain information that is discriminatory for the classes you have, then it doesn't matter how much training data or how many trees you use, it'll still be a bad classification.

1. Use `stratifiedSample` instead of a bunch of random samples + reduceRegions.  There's a lot of complex geometries involved and using whole tables as a geometry is expensive.  You also wont have to post-filter for null values, since stratifiedSample doesn't allow for null values by default.
2. Cast your covariate stack to `float`; several of the bands are doubles.
3. Use `minLeafPopulation` to limit the size of the trees.
4. Don't bother with resubstitution accuracy at all; it's not giving you any information and just wastes time/memory.
5. You're sampling again with your already sampled validation points.  No need.

You're already using >40,000 points for training; you should consider refining your feature vector instead of hoping that more points does a better job.  What's in there now? (See this video for suggestions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WvaBZbph_cU)

https://code.earthengine.google.com/fc6887dd71192cbbf8d5f90f1d5c9ea7

Comment: Dear @ Noel, I am beyond grateful for your answer. I have spent days not able to solve it. I will consider all the points that you provide it here. Thank you.